# Rounding and displaying exact value

Tags: c++, rounding, cout

Guys I have a question:

`39268112/50000000*4` is **exactly** `3.14144896`

But when i write a code in c++ as such:

```
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int a = 39268112;
   int b = 50000000;
   cout << (double)a / (double)b * 4;
}
```

> But, I get **3.14145**.

This is not the exact value. 
**So my question is:**

> how can i always display the exact value of a `double` division?

EDIT: I am aware of the setprecision option, the problem here is just, that I have to know the exact value of the result to know how many decimals the result will have. Since I wrote a program, which approximates PI based on dart throws, the two integers a and b can have much bigger values than 39268112 and 5000000.

If I would use

```
cout << setprecision(some number) << (double)a / (double)b * 4;
```

I need to know the exact result first, before I can even enter the argument in setprecision()

My edited question would be if there is a way to automaticly put an argument in setprecision() so that it can display the exact result, without having to calculate it myself first.

Comment: look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: so precision is set to 5 by default?

Comment: @StefanB Try `std::cout << std::setprecision(12) <<   (double)a / (double)b * 4;`

Comment: btw, I think there is one too much `0` since it's giving me [31.4144...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=39268112%2F5000000*4)

Comment: Actually, 39'268'112 / 5'000'000 * 4 is *exactly* 31,4144896.